# Realtime Database Iterator

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to iterate the key in my real-time database, I saw some answers from the past with similar question but it doesn't work on mine. So I need your help once more. I used .push and I tried arraylist but arraylist is a bad idea to be a dynamic output in realtime database.

[image]

Comment: sound you need dictionary if you want fast access,

Comment: "It doesn't work on mine" -> "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"